# C# MySqlConnector next query in the same connection

Tags: c#, .net, mysql-connector, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I have the following code:

```
string myConnection = "server=localhost;database=test;uid=test;password=test";
        string query = "SELECT label_type, label, quantity FROM system_printserver WHERE print=0";
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            myConn.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, myConn);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
            printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);

            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (myReader.Read()) {
                orderNumber = myReader.GetString(1);
                myReader.Close();
                string queryOrder = "SELECT id_order, id_carrier FROM ps_orders WHERE id_order=28329";
                MySqlCommand commandOrder = new MySqlCommand(queryOrder, myConn);

                MySqlDataReader myReaderOrder;
                myReaderOrder = commandOrder.ExecuteReader();
                idCarrier = myReaderOrder.GetString(1);
                printDocument1.Print();
            }
```

I have a problem because the second query string queryOrder doesn't work. The query is Ok but variable "idCarrier" doesn't accept any value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can attach another reader to a connection, when one is already open and processing records. You must retrieve all your records first, i.e. ToList() or Dataset, or use a secondary connection for the second reader.

To make your life easier, consider using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) or [Linq2Db](https://github.com/linq2db), two awesome micro-ORMs.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
using(var connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=test;uid=test;password=test") {
    connection.Open();
    int orderNumber = 0;
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
         command.CommandText = @"SELECT label_type, label, quantity FROM system_printserver WHERE print=0";
         DataTable data = new DataTable();
         adapter.Fill(data);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

         var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);

         if(reader.Read()) {
             orderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetString(1));
         }
    }

    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = string.format(@"SELECT id_order, id_carrier FROM ps_orders WHERE id_order={0}",orderNumber);
        var reader =  command.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.Read()){
            printDocument1.Print();
            return reader.GetString(1);
        }
    }
}
```